# Incorrect content alignment inside ListView

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml, listviewitem

I am working on UWP app and I found issue with content alignment inside the ListView. As doc say, we should use ListView.VerticalContentAlignment property to align content, but I find out, that the property is ignored and default value is used instead.

For example this simple app:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Data}" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Where code behind is just this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }


    public List<string> Data { get; set; } = new List<string>()
    {
        "a","b","c","d","e"
    };
}
```

Have following output:
[image]

Althougth the ListView.VerticalContentAlignment is set. I check the ListViewItemPresenter (TextBlock container) in Live Visual Tree and default value is there, but ignored and ListViewItemPresenterVerticalContentAlignment used instead.

[image]

The [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.listviewitempresenter#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_ListViewItemPresenter_ListViewItemPresenterVerticalContentAlignmentProperty) say, that I should use `ContentPresenter.VerticalContentAlignmentProperty` instead of `ListViewItemPresenterVerticalContentAlignmentProperty`. Is it just bug, or am I doing something wrong? Is there way to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe you can try to modify the ItemContainerStyle like this:

```
<ListView ...>
  <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
    </Style>
  </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView
```

Answer (score 0):

The ListView.VerticalContentAlignment is aligning the listview to the top of the form.  The items in your horizontal listview are aligned to the center.  Try setting the alignment on the textBlock

```
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I tried it but without success. I really think that this is just a bug, because when I open Live Visual Tree- right click on ListViewItemPresenter - Show Properties and change VerticalContentAlignment property to something else and then back to "Top", the item is aligned correctly and ListViewItemPresenterVerticalContentAlignment property have correct value.

Answer (score 0):

@Patrik
I also observed this issue and noticed that if i cut and paste this ItemContainerStyle in listview properties (xaml) while debugger is running, vertical content alignment is applied else it is not.
I fixed this by adding ItemContainerStyle inside the listview style and now it seems to work( applied at all times).

P.S. This question is from a while ago, however, posting this just to help someone else seeing this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).